# how to know space of drive is finished when i write video with VideoWriter opencv

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

i want monitor and control production line of factory with vision. for now i want install camera in factory and record video of production line for 24 hours for a week, i want use opencv and `VideoWriter`.

my problem is because i want record video in `FULLHD` resolution and `30fps` the size of video become extremely large maybe several hundred GB even TR, for this i need to know when a drive become full and close current video and change path from a one drive to another and again write video(i have several drive and hard disk) and if not exist any space stop recording.

thanks.

Comment: It depends what operating system you are using.

Comment: my operating system is windows 10.

Comment: `GetDiskFreeSpace()` maybe?

Comment: "video ... maybe several hundred GB" -- that sounds vastly impractical. I would go for relatively short (say 10 minutes, few GB tops) files, with timestamped filenames, and take inspiration from log files and log rotation.

Comment: why its vastly impractical ? why you are so surprise ?

Comment: Multi-gigabyte files are harder to backup, harder to copy, more likely to get corrupted... Dan’s advice is good.

Comment: this is for test i want save video and maybe create dataset and test different algorithms and ...

Answer (score 0):

The best Software design that i know for your Task is to split-off your recording executeable and write a totally separate disk-Monitor executeable.

This disk-Monitor would check the drive usage every x time Units and if the drive is full, stop the current and spawn a new recording Task, handing over the next drive to write at as Parameter.

This comes from your recording Task having such a huge lifetime while relying on such instable resources like Harddrive, Cameras etc... It is pretty common that those low-level resources can cause Errors in your application that leads to an unwanted Exit.

And my recommendation to check for disk space is to use WMI on Windows 10.

Comment: Sorry we dont write your Code here. Thats what the guys on codeproject do: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3921/Disk-free-space